# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `laravel 5.5` framework.It requirements `PHP >= 7.0.0`.
when I run server I got this error (`php artisan serve`):

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in E:\xampp\htdocs\dibit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 233
```

I've installed the last version of xampp and phpstorm.

I think this error show I'm not using php 7.

[image]

in my console of my phpstorm when I run this commend:

```
php -v
```

it returns `PHP 5.6.21`.

where is my problem?

the result of this code:

```
<?php

echo phpversion();

?>
```

is:

```
7.2.1



http://localhost/p.php
```

---

I have two xampp software but them have been installed an

Comment: Have you checked `E:\xampp\htdocs\dibit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 233`? Maybe there is something wrong?

Comment: helpers.php line 233??

Comment: The php executable for the CLI might be still using the old 5.6 version. Most probably the php short-code might not be enabled. pls check the above file

Comment: error line code: `return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] ?? null);`

Comment: I think php -v command in phpstrom should return 7.21.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you installed the PPA 7.1.8 as CLI only (php7-cli). You're getting your version info from that, but your libapache2-mod-php package is still 14.04 main which is 5.6. Check your phpinfo in your browser to confirm the version. You might also consider migrating to Ubuntu 16.04 to get PHP 7.0 in main.

Comment: update PHP version first

Comment: Also, this error occurs while using the command line its because you must be using php 7 to execute whatever it is you are trying to execute. What happened is that the code is trying to use an operator thats only available in php7+ and is causing a syntax error. Hope you understand!

Comment: are you also serving the php script with echo phpversion(); using the same artisan serve command?

Comment: How did you execute echo phpversion();? I may guest you execute script that show phpversion by XAMPP (not serve by php cli but put it in htdocs) that the phpversion is 7.2.1. However your php cli (check your PATH environment) is only 5.6. Let try to serve echo phpversion(); by php cli to confirm. If it's true, set your PATH environment point to XAMPP php path

Comment: It looks to me like your command prompt uses an old php version. To make sure that, run "where php" in a command prompt and find out whether it prints the right path. If it's incorrect, check the PATH environment variable and put the content here.

Comment: `where php` helped me. it returns two paths of php: C:... E:.. . I removed C:.. path and worked as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like your command prompt uses an old php version. To confirm that, run

`where php`

in a command prompt and find out whether it prints the right path (to PHP7). If it's incorrect, check the PATH environment variable and modify it with the correct path to PHP7.

Hope it helps.